# Connecting to Ubuntu machines with direct ethernet (one Lubuntu) not working

Tags: ethernet, lan, sharing

I'm connecting an Ubuntu 12.04 and a Lubuntu 15.? machine via direct ethernet and have had no success. I have pop-up notifications that 'connection is established' on one machine, but I cant share internet, ping, share folders etc., and have immediate disconnection on the other machine.

The error I get when I ping from one machine is:
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted

I usually get 'unresponsive' when I ping from the other.

I have tried a crossover adapter, I have used the same cable to connect other machines, have deleted iptables, set it to allow ip forwarding, etc, and still nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the two pinging by turning off the firewall using:

```
 sudo ufw disable
```

Nothing else in any help forums helped. Still can't share my wireless internet connection via the ethernet connection. Next step I guess.